# Assigning customers a household_id based off matched customer fields (phone, email, address) - trouble with duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a customer table in which each customer has a unique `id` dependent on the email they placed their order with. Additionally, there are separate table columns for `phone`, `email`, and `address`. I am trying to group customer ids together under the same `household_id` if their `phone`, `email`, or `address` matches to another "customer" in the customer table.

The problem I am running into is that I can group customers together and give them a `household_id`, but I am struggling to fully remove duplicate occurrences of these customer groupings in my filtering. The last two comments in my below query are meant to help explain my current filtering logic and illustrate where it's failing. This logic works for pairs of customers, but starts to fail once 3 or more customers need to be tied to the same, single household_id. Is there a better way I should be filtering these results, or do I need to add some additional CTE that makes use of min()/max() functions and some other sort of grouping to add in more intelligence here? Any other clever window functions that could help me out here besides rank()?

```sql
with household as (
  select
    c1.id as parent_id,
    c2.id as child_id,
    rank() over (partition by c1.id order by c2.id) as child_number
    -- order by clause is important here to ensure lowest c2.id is always rank 1 (referenced later on in household join onto customer table)
                    
  from customer c1
    left join customer c2 on (c1.phone = c2.phone) or (c1.email = c2.email) or (c1.address = c2.address)
                            
  order by c1.id, child_number
)
                
select
  'H-' || h.parent_id as household_id, -- effectively creates a unique household_id
  h.child_id
                    
from household h
  where h.parent_id < h.child_id or (h.parent_id = h.child_id and h.child_number = 1)
  -- ^this where clause is my attempt at removing the duplicate groupings of customers
  -- it works in the instance when there is a pair of customers tied to a household_id, but when there are 3 or more it starts to fail
```

See linked picture for a of view of the household cte for a grouping of 3 customer_id's that are joined together because they have a matching phone, email, or address. The highlighted row is what will get past my filter in the where clause of the above query

[How my query is failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixGtM.png)

Comment: You write you have "unique id dependent on the email", jet from your problem I see you allow email duplicates. How is id dependant on the email ?

Comment: that's a fair point, I should remove the email = email clause, thanks. The larger problem of creating an extra/unwanted household id for the same/similar grouping of customer ids will still exist though

Comment: The household in your case has key email, phone, address (should be just address in my opinion, but its up to you). Why not use these attributes to identify the houshold? Why new id?

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis actually I take my earlier comment back. I need to keep the email = email join clause in there for the case that a customer does not have any other matches, I still need to write that customer id and assign it to a household_id

Comment: purely grouping on just the address is not intelligent enough. addresses are messy and require a lot of normalization. also, some customers can have multiple addresses (main residence and lake house for example)

Comment: What result do you expect in case of customers: A(email_A, phone_A), B(email_B, phone_B) and C(email_A, phone_B) ? How many households are there in this case ?

Comment: I would like for that to be a single household. Customer C is effectively linking customers A and B together. Keep in mind this doesn't happen though because your customer C has email_A so there is no unique customer id written for them and they have the same id as customer A

Comment: Do you have many customers? Should the query perform well?

Comment: it does not need to be super performant. ~50,000 customers

Comment: From what you describe it seems to require recursive CTE to join all the houshold members array to every person and then removing the member group dublicates.

Comment: I was a bit afraid of this, but it's definitely good to hear this from someone else before going down that rabbit hole myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using a similar method to what was discussed in the comments w/ Julius:

1. Grouped all the like customers into arrays using a recursive cte `grp`
2. Trimmed the recursive `grp` down to only the arrays with all the household members using `select distinct on` and the `cardinality()` function in the `household` cte
3. Scanned through the `household` table and removed any duplicates by unnesting the `linked_customers` array and tie-ing all its elements to a single `household_id` based off the minimum id in the array

This seems to work pretty well, but I'm sure this query can be further simplified, and I would happily welcome any feedback!

```sql
with recursive grp as (
    select
        c1.id,
        c1.email,
        c1.phone,
        c1.address,
        array[c1.id] as linked_customers -- initializes an array based of the id of every customer
    from customer c1
    
    union all
    
    select
        c2.id,
        c2.email,
        c2.phone,
        c2.address,
        c2.id || linked_customers
    from grp g
        join customer c2 on (g.email = c2.email or g.phone = c2.phone or g.address = c2.address)
    where c2.id <> all(linked_customers) -- ensures the same customer id that already was used in the array initialization is not being looked at again
), -- creates several similar groups as well as intermediary groups of customers

household as (
    select
        distinct on (g.id) g.linked_customers
    from grp g
    order by g.id, cardinality(linked_customers) desc
) -- extracts largest array for each customer_id (still duplicate groupings here), but only the max length arrays are being pulled out (all household members)

select
    distinct on (p.parent_id) 'H-' || parent_id as household_id,
    unnest(p.linked_customers) as child_id
from (
    select
        min(parent_id) as parent_id, -- pulls out the minimum id of each linked customers group which will remove the creation of multiple household_ids for the same customer groups in the select clause above
        h.linked_customers
    from household h, unnest(h.linked_customers) parent_id
    group by h.linked_customers
) p
order by parent_id
```